# What does my ACF and PACF plots indicate for ARIMA order?

Tags: forecasting, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I am looking at forecasting first-order differences oil prices using the ARIMA models. However, I struggle to see what p and q orders my ACF and PACF plots would indicate.

I have added the act and pacf under, where the first lag at lags=0 is excluded for better visualizing, as it was 1 for both plots.

So, how would you interpret these plots?[image]

Comment: Selection of ARIMA orders by ACF and PACF has historically been a popular method, but state of the art order selection is based on information criteria. See e.g. the `auto.arima` method in R. This automated algorithm is presented in a journal article and described in several other sources.

Comment: Good comment by @Richard Hardy. It seems like there might be seasonality in your data, since these correlograms spike at 12 and multiples of 12. You might have to use a SARIMA.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with using the classical approach to ARIMA (looking at ACF or PACF or similar tests) is that (many think) they don't work well when you have both AR and MA terms.

Aside from auto.arima there are methods devised by authors such as Tsay (ESCAF, MINIC, SCAN is what SAS calls these) that also suggests various models to test.